# Is it possible to use nameserver and CNAME with a domain on namecheap?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, nameserver, cname-record

I have a domain on namecheap that is currently pointing to AWS servers, a la:

```
ns-1353.awsdns-24.org
ns-1069.awsdns-09.co.uk
ns-161.awsdns-62.com
ns-699.awsdns-40.net
```

I'm trying to setup a subdomain so that I can have a courses site on the same domain: eg. courses.domain.com

Within namecheap's interface, I cannot seem to both use the nameservers as well as the CNAME. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you point your domain to AWS, it is managed there and you have to add any entries, including for CNAMES and subdomains on the AWS DNS, not at Namecheap.